# JDA Discord using modals (slash commands) working only on debug mode

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

im using first time discord modals (slash commands) on JDA. When I export the bot and turn it on, the commands appear under / (slash commands) they do not work, it shows "The application is not responding"

```
JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
                .setActivity(Activity.listening("TEST"))
                .addEventListeners(new TestCommand())
                .build().awaitReady();





        Guild guild = jda.getGuildById("SERVER_ID");


        if (guild != null){
            guild.upsertCommand("test", "test command").queue();
        }
```

*TestCommand*

```
@Override
    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {

        if (event.getName().equals("test")){

            TextInput test_name = TextInput.create("test-name", "Name", TextInputStyle.SHORT)
                    .setPlaceholder("test text")
                    .setMinLength(1)
                    .setRequired(true)
                    .build();

            TextInput message = TextInput.create("test-message","Message", TextInputStyle.PARAGRAPH)
                    .setMinLength(10)
                    .setMaxLength(100)
                    .setRequired(true)
                    .setValue("test text.")
                    .build();

            Modal modal = Modal.create("test-modal", "test text")
                    .addActionRows(ActionRow.of(name), ActionRow.of(message))
                    .build();

            event.replyModal(modal).queue();
```

If turn it on IntelliJ debug mode and enable the bot without exporting, the slash commands / work normally.

Comment: Is it possible you are using a different token?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Are you sure that the bot is actually running? Try adding a print statement to the beginning of your listener and see if it prints anything.

Comment: Other functions work normally

Answer (score 0):

Change for this:

```
            Modal modal = Modal.create("test-modal", "test text")
                .addActionRows(ActionRow.of(test_name), ActionRow.of(message))
                .build();
```

Comment: it would be great if you could give some explanation as to how your answer fixes the question